# In python how to I make [x , y] into individual variables?

Tags: python

I'm working with an API that returns variables in this format:

```
[x, y]
```

How can I take that and turn it into individual x and y variables?

Comment: you could do first, second = <somereturned>

Comment: Take a look at the Python documentation before posting a question like this. The internet is filled with plenty of excellent resources regarding learning Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
>>> a,b = [1, 2]
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do

`first, second = somethingReturned`

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing the data you retrieve from your API to another function, you don't have to unpack them by hand, just use the star operator.

```
my_func(*api_func())
```